# Specific divs in between blocks of front page in drupal html

Tags: html, drupal-7, drupal-views

Im not sure if i correct mentioned topic. But here is what i have to do

```
 <div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="block block-views">...</div>
```

How do i put     `<div class="clear">`     after each  2(!) blocks? to avoid using .block-views:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: left; }. The amount of blocks can vary from 2 to 10. I need this for blocks floating.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo describes a method for styling every other class.   It might help?  Otherwise, I believe that blocks are rendered as some kind of countable array.  You can access that array to count the number being rendered via PHP.  Set up a counter or iterate through the array using the counter embedded in the array.  Print `<div class="clear"></div>`, every other time, as part of your loop....

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using CSS, try this:

```
<div id="view-1" class="block block-views">...</div>
<div id="view-2" class="block block-views">...</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="view-3" class="block block-views">...</div>
<div id="view-4" class="block block-views">...</div>
```

And in your css, write this code:

```
#view-2:after, #view-4:after
{
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

You should get the same results as if you're using your `.clear` div.

Hope this works... Muhammad.